# Alimentar blog desde otro blog

Tags: wordpress

Estoy estoy empezando a trabajar con Wordpress y me pidieron que haga lo siguiente:

Tengo 4 páginas tipo blog:

- Noticias: Donde se podrá subir texto, imagen y documento
- Normativas: El cual tendrá un árbol de normativas y se podrán poner documentos
- Recomendaciones: Igual que normativas.

Lo que necesito es:

1. El Home sería:

   - Barra de menú
   - Slider principal
   - **Novedades** (Donde irían las últimas subidas al blog de noticias, normativas y recomendaciones)
   - Formulario de contacto

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo lleno el blog del Home desde las últimas entradas a *Noticias/Normativas/Recomendaciones*? ¿Se puede hacer?

2. Si, debe ser medio obvia pero todavía no entiendo muy bien Wordpress, Puedo hacer que el Home tenga parte estática (Slider, formulario contacto) y dinámica (ultimas entradas de los blogs)?

Comment: La respuesta a la segunda pregunta es: **Sí**.

Comment: ¿Puedes especificar a qué WP te refieres? Hay sitios de Wordpress.com que son gratuitos y muy limitados, o puedes tener tu propio dominio alojado en WP, entonces hablaríamos de Wordpress.org, aquí tienes más posibilidades. De todos modos, WP viene ya con opciones preparadas para casi todo lo que quieres hacer y hay Themes gratuitos que presentan un slider donde quieras, hay Widgets que presentan las últimas entradas, comentarios, y otras cosas. Luego tendrías que aprender a modificar los templates (plantillas), al principio parece complicado pero no lo es. Hay temas de pago también.

Answer (score 0):

la gracia de Wordpress es, precisamente esa
deberias mirar el sitio del codex, especificamente en el apartado de desarrollo de themes para que puedas ir aclarando tus dudas.

https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Desarrollo_de_Temas

Te recomiendo partir con esto

- https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a empezar por la pregunta

1. Para listar los POST, pode usar el siguiente codigo

```
if(have_post()): // verifica si hay post/s a listar

while(have_post()): //loop

the_post(); // pone el indice en el siguiente post a listar

?>

<article>

<h1><?php echo the_title();  ?></h1>

</article>

<?php

endwhile

else:

echo "No hay entradas";

endif;
```

2. lo mas facil es crear un archivo llamado "front-end.php" en el directorio del tema. Este PHP se va a cargar cuando entres en la home. Para mas referencia esta imagen te explica como es la cascada de carga para los archivos del template [image]. 
   Igualmente como dijo @Hugosolar mira la DOC en https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Desarrollo_de_Temas